# unable to conect to VM and k8s pod in hazelcast

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Is it possible to activate normal discovery as well as Kubernetes discovery at the same time? Actually what I am trying to do is I have different services already running and connected to hazelcast. I want one service to connect to a service that is running on a VM which is not a part of the k8s cluster.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright 2017 Red Hat, Inc.
  ~
  ~ Red Hat licenses this file to you under the Apache License, version 2.0
  ~ (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the
  ~ License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  ~
  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
  ~ WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.  See the
  ~ License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
  ~ under the License.
  -->

<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.10.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <properties>
    <property name="hazelcast.mancenter.enabled">false</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.memcache.enabled">false</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.rest.enabled">false</property>
    <property name="hazelcast.wait.seconds.before.join">5</property>
    <property name ="hazelcast.socket.bind.any">false</property>
  </properties>


  <management-center enabled="false">http://localhost:8080/mancenter</management-center>
  <network>
    <port auto-increment="true" port-count="10000">5730</port>
    <outbound-ports>
      <!--
      Allowed port range when connecting to other nodes.
      0 or * means use system provided port.
      -->
      <ports>0</ports>
    </outbound-ports>
    <join>
      <multicast enabled="false">
        <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
        <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
      </multicast>
      <tcp-ip enabled="true">
        <interface>10.0.2.17</interface>
        <interface>10.0.4.21</interface>
      </tcp-ip>
      <aws enabled="false">
        <access-key>my-access-key</access-key>
        <secret-key>my-secret-key</secret-key>
        <!--optional, default is us-east-1 -->
        <region>us-west-1</region>
        <!--optional, default is ec2.amazonaws.com. If set, region shouldn't be set as it will override this property -->
        <host-header>ec2.amazonaws.com</host-header>
        <!-- optional, only instances belonging to this group will be discovered, default will try all running instances -->
        <security-group-name>hazelcast-sg</security-group-name>
        <tag-key>type</tag-key>
        <tag-value>hz-nodes</tag-value>
      </aws>
    </join>
    <interfaces enabled="false">
      <interface>10.10.1.*</interface>
    </interfaces>
    <ssl enabled="false"/>
    <socket-interceptor enabled="false"/>
    <symmetric-encryption enabled="false">
      <!--
         encryption algorithm such as
         DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding,
         PBEWithMD5AndDES,
         AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding,
         Blowfish,
         DESede
      -->
      <algorithm>PBEWithMD5AndDES</algorithm>
      <!-- salt value to use when generating the secret key -->
      <salt>thesalt</salt>
      <!-- pass phrase to use when generating the secret key -->
      <password>thepass</password>
      <!-- iteration count to use when generating the secret key -->
      <iteration-count>19</iteration-count>
    </symmetric-encryption>
  </network>
  <partition-group enabled="false"/>
  <executor-service name="default">
    <pool-size>16</pool-size>
    <!--Queue capacity. 0 means Integer.MAX_VALUE.-->
    <queue-capacity>0</queue-capacity>
  </executor-service>

  <multimap name="__vertx.subs">

    <!--
        Number of backups. If 1 is set as the backup-count for example,
        then all entries of the map will be copied to another JVM for
        fail-safety. 0 means no backup.
    -->
    <backup-count>1</backup-count>
  </multimap>

  <map name="__vertx.haInfo">

    <!--
        Number of backups. If 1 is set as the backup-count for example,
        then all entries of the map will be copied to another JVM for
        fail-safety. 0 means no backup.
    -->
    <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    <!--
  Maximum number of seconds for each entry to stay in the map. Entries that are
  older than <time-to-live-seconds> and not updated for <time-to-live-seconds>
  will get automatically evicted from the map.
  Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means infinite. Default is 0.
-->
    <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
    <!--
  Maximum number of seconds for each entry to stay idle in the map. Entries that are
  idle(not touched) for more than <max-idle-seconds> will get
  automatically evicted from the map. Entry is touched if get, put or containsKey is called.
  Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means infinite. Default is 0.
-->
    <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
    <!--
        Valid values are:
        NONE (no eviction),
        LRU (Least Recently Used),
        LFU (Least Frequently Used).
        NONE is the default.
    -->
    <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>
    <!--
        Maximum size of the map. When max size is reached,
        map is evicted based on the policy defined.
        Any integer between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE. 0 means
        Integer.MAX_VALUE. Default is 0.
    -->
    <max-size policy="PER_NODE">0</max-size>
    <!--
        When max. size is reached, specified percentage of
        the map will be evicted. Any integer between 0 and 100.
        If 25 is set for example, 25% of the entries will
        get evicted.
    -->
    <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
    <!--
        While recovering from split-brain (network partitioning),
        map entries in the small cluster will merge into the bigger cluster
        based on the policy set here. When an entry merge into the
        cluster, there might an existing entry with the same key already.
        Values of these entries might be different for that same key.
        Which value should be set for the key? Conflict is resolved by
        the policy set here. Default policy is PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy
        There are built-in merge policies such as
        com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy; entry will be added if there is no existing entry for the key.
        com.hazelcast.map.merge.PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy ; entry will be added if the merging entry doesn't exist in the cluster.
        com.hazelcast.map.merge.HigherHitsMapMergePolicy ; entry with the higher hits wins.
        com.hazelcast.map.merge.LatestUpdateMapMergePolicy ; entry with the latest update wins.
    -->
    <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.LatestUpdateMapMergePolicy</merge-policy>

  </map>

  <!-- Used internally in Vert.x to implement async locks -->
  <semaphore name="__vertx.*">
    <initial-permits>1</initial-permits>
  </semaphore>

</hazelcast>
```

Comment: It is unrelated to Hazelcast, but to Kubernetes instead. The question should be reworded as: "How a container scheduled on a Kubernetes cluster can access machines outside of it?"

Comment: the XML that I have attached is able to connect two VMs. below I am attaching a different XML which is useful in connecting all K8s pod. I just want some configuration using which I can run on K8s and will connect to all pods as well as the I can connect to the outside machine's hazelcast service.

Comment: ```<network>
   <join>
     <multicast enabled="false"/>
      <tcp-ip enabled="false:/>

     <discovery-strategies>
       <discovery-strategy enabled="true"
           class="com.hazelcast.kubernetes.HazelcastKubernetesDiscoveryStrategy">
         <properties>
           <property name="service-dns">service-hazelcast-server.default.svc.cluster.local</property>
         </properties>
       </discovery-strategy>
     </discovery-strategies>
   </join>
 </network>```

Comment: both configs are hazelcast member side configs. Are you using hazelcast-client? Are your services written in Java? Discovery on Kubernetes only available in Java for both client and member side. If you update your question based on those comments then I can try to help you.

Comment: And short answer to your question is that you can only use one discovery strategy at a time in both hazelcast client and member side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to have multiple discovery strategies (joiners) and the same time. Please check [this](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/config/JoinConfig.java#L182) for details.